# правильно ли поставлены знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика

С 1 января в связи, с изменениями штатного расписания переназначит Тууганбекову Мадину Каныбековну с должности кассира на должность Бухгалтера-Кассира, с окладом согласно штатному расписанию.

Answer (score 1):

Первая запятая не на месте; оборот, начинающийся со "в связи", требует обособления ввиду его расположения *внутри* предложения.
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1

Слово "переназначить" здесь не совсем точное: очень часто оно обозначает *повторное назначение* на ту же должность.

> С 1 января, в связи с изменениями штатного расписания, *перевести*
>   Тууганбекову Мадину Каныбековну с должности кассира на должность
>   бухгалтера-кассира, с окладом согласно штатному расписанию.